# Python, string formatting, strange output

Tags: python, string, formatting

I have this string

```
q="""insert into genres (movieid,%(genre_name)s) values (%(movieid)i,1)""" % {'genre_name': t2, 'movieid': movieid}
```

but the result of `print q` is

> ) values (1,1)nres (movieid,adventure

instead of

> insert into genres (movieid,adventure) values (1,1)

why?

Comment: I get the good result, could you give more context, and print t2 and movieid also ?

Comment: I guess the content of "genre_name" contains a \r (carriage return, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRLF) character or some other crap that makes the display goes wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your movie `genre_name` has carriage return.

Example:

```
q="""insert into genres (movieid,%(genre_name)s) values (%(movieid)i,1)""" % {'genre_name': 'horro\r', 'movieid': 12}

print q
```

gives:

`) values (12,1)res (movieid,horro`

You should sanitize your input. It's strange to have a backslash there, but maybe change it to forward slash or make it `adventure(r)`.

Comment: I agree `q="""insert into genres (movieid,%(genre_name)s) values (%(movieid)i,1)""" % {'genre_name': "adventure\r", 'movieid': 1}` give your result

Comment: Thanks. Now i sanitize my input with str.strip() method